# Login Bug when password is wrong

Tags: c#, authentication, uwp

I made the application before going to the Store Page then required to login first. So checked first. When it did log in, it can Directly navigate to the Store Page. But if not logged in, the user must login and after clicking the login button, it will navigate to the "Store" Page. Likewise if you want to navigate to the "Koleksi" Page.

I'm having a problem, that despite the wrong password can still log in and headed Store Page or "Koleksi" Page. This happens when I add functionality to navigate to the Store Page or "Koleksi" Page. Before adding the function, if the password is wrong, can not login.
XAML:

```
<Image x:Name="store" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="150" Height="150" Margin="20,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Tapped="store_Tapped" Source="images/new icon/BSE-book-icon-store.png"/>
                <Image x:Name="bukukoleksi" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="150" Height="150" Margin="20,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Tapped="koleksi_Tapped" Source="images/new icon/bse-icon300-w8-KOLEKSI.png"/>

<callisto:CustomDialog x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="LoginDialog" 
                       Title="Login"
                       Background="#FFFCDAA2" BackButtonVisibility="Collapsed" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <StackPanel x:Name="loginBox">
                <TextBlock x:Name="spacerLogin" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" Width="300" Height="50" Text=""/>
                <Grid x:Name="loginEnter">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock x:Name="FailedMessage" FontSize="17" Text="Login failed!" Foreground="Red" Visibility="Collapsed" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="email" Text="Email:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,10,0,0" FontSize="18" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FFCA6402"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="emailBox" PlaceholderText="Email" FontSize="17" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,10,0,0" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="password" Text="Password:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" FontSize="18" Height="40" Margin="0,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FFCA6402"/>
                    <PasswordBox x:Name="passwordBox" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" PlaceholderText="Password" FontSize="18" Height="40" Margin="10,10,0,0"/>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <Button x:Name="loginBtn" Background="#FFCA6402" Content="Login" Margin="0,20,0,0" FontWeight="SemiBold" Click="loginBtn_Click" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1"/>
                        <Button x:Name="cancelLoginBtn" Background="#FFCA6402" Content="Batal" Margin="20,20,0,0" FontWeight="SemiBold" Click="cancelLoginBtn_Click" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <ProgressRing x:Name="loadingLogin" Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Width="50" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FFCA6402" IsActive="False"/>
                </Grid>
```

Code:

```
bool isstoreTapped = false;
  bool iskoleksiTapped = false;
  private void loginBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
      loadingLogin.IsActive = true;
      FailedMessage.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
      ProsesLogin();
      if(isstoreTapped==true)
      {
          this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Store));
      }
      if(iskoleksiTapped==true)
      {
          this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(koleksibuku.KolesiPage));
      }

  }

 private async void ProsesLogin()
        {
            FailedMessage.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            loadingLogin.IsActive = true;
            try
            {
                var filter = new Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
                filter.ServerCredential = new Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordCredential("BSE_Win10(1)", "mahonidatastream", "Maho1019");
                var client = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient(filter);
                string urlPath = "https://...m/user/auth";
                var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("email", emailBox.Text),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password",passwordBox.Password)
                };
                var response = await client.PostAsync(new Uri(urlPath), new Windows.Web.Http.HttpFormUrlEncodedContent(values));
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    //RequestException();
                    loadingLogin.IsActive = false;
                }

                string jsonText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                JsonObject jsonObject = JsonObject.Parse(jsonText);
                bool error = jsonObject["error"].GetBoolean();
                //string message = jsonObject["message"].GetString();
                if (error == false)
                {
                    LoginDialog.IsOpen = false;
                    FailedMessage.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    ((App)(App.Current)).UserName = emailBox.Text;
                    loadingLogin.IsActive = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    FailedMessage.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    FailedMessage.Text = "Email atau password tidak sesuai/belum terdaftar";
                    loadingLogin.IsActive = false;
                }

            }
            catch (HttpRequestException ex)
            {
                //ConnectionException();
                loadingLogin.IsActive = false;
            }
        }

  private void store_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
  {
      if (((App)(App.Current)).UserName == "Sign in to your account")
      {
          LoginDialog.IsOpen = true;
          loginDetail.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
          loginEnter.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
          emailBox.Text = "";
          passwordBox.Password = "";
          isstoreTapped = true;
          iskoleksiTapped = false;
      }
      else
      {
          this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Store));
      }
  }

  private void koleksi_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
  {
      if (((App)(App.Current)).UserName == "Sign in to your account")
      {
          LoginDialog.IsOpen = true;
          loginDetail.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
          loginEnter.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
          emailBox.Text = "";
          passwordBox.Password = "";
          iskoleksiTapped = true;
          isstoreTapped = false;
      }
      else
      {
          this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(koleksibuku.KolesiPage));
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have navigate flags, you may be able set them as false also when login failed. In that case when login failed it will not navigate. For example:

```
 //Your code
  catch (HttpRequestException ex)
  {
      //ConnectionException();
      loadingLogin.IsActive = false;
  }
  //Add following code
  if (loadingLogin.IsActive == false)
  {
      isstoreTapped = false;
      iskoleksiTapped = false;
  }
```

Adding this code block to last of the `ProcessLogin()` method.

Comment: I've added code:
if (loadingLogin.IsActive == false)
  {
      isstoreTapped = false;
      iskoleksiTapped = false;
  } 
on ProgressLogin (); but when clicking storeBtn and enter your email and password, even though the password is entered can still headed Store Page.